# Cleaner way of authenticating with active directory?

Tags: php, ldap

Where I work, we use anonymous directory access because of some smtp server that needs it. I don't know the specifics. For a project I'm working on, I wanted to use active directory logins. Problem I ran into, I can't check if ldap == true because it will /always/ equal true. Also, I'm doing the entire login and displaying content on one page without javascript.

Here's what I've done:

```
$adServer = 'ipaddress';
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($adServer)
or $this->msg = "Could not connect to LDAP server.";
//Begin magic to compensate for anonymous directory access while still locking out anonymous users
if($_POST["password"] == null)
{
$password = "invalid";
}
else $password = $_POST["password"];
$ldaprdn = "domain\\" . $_POST["username"];
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $password);

if($ldapbind) {
$loggedin = true;
}
elseif(isset($_POST["password"]) && !$_POST["password"] == null) {
$msg = "Incorrect username or password";
$loggedin = false;
}
else {$loggedin = false;}
```

Basically hard coding in a false password and waiting for the login form to pass in an authentic one. This system works, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner/easier/faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects to an LDAP directory server, that connection has an **unauthenticated** authorization state. LDAP clients can use the BIND request to request that the server change the authorization state of the connection to the state associated with the information in the BIND request (in the Simple BIND request, the only information is the DN and the password). Once the connection's authorization state has been successfully changed, further operations on that connection are conducted with that authorization state until:

- A new BIND request arrives on the connection
- The connection is terminated by the client or the server.

This is how "authentication" works with LDAP. You've encapsulated that, more or less, in your code snippet, though you're not checking for response controls that may have arrived with the BIND response.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with `ldap` but is a more generic question like: *how do I do form validation in PHP?*

```
if (isset($_POST["password"]) === false) {
    throw new Exception("Missing input");
}
if (is_string($_POST["password"]) === false) {
    throw new Exception("Bad input");
}
// now you now password exists, and it's a string so you can pass it to ldap
```

Comment: Well, not exactly. My question was more asking if there was a better way to authenticate through ldap if anonymous directory access is allowed. In the code I provided, I'm hard coding in a place-holder password until the user fills out the login input fields. Once that happens, `$_POST["password"]` is no longer `null`.

Comment: `$_POST["password"]` is never `null`. It's either undefined (which will give you a warning if you try to access it) or it is a value, possibly a string.

Comment: Well, no it is. Upon loading the page without any session information, `$_POST["password"]` is indeed null. This is confirmed by echo'ing `$password`

Comment: Ok, let's take a step back here. Let's make sure you've set up your development environment properly. Set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. You should see a warning.

Comment: `username` and `password` are both undefined